# How to use special characters for cms pages meta description in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I Added a meta description for CMS page from the admin,
meta description contain a apostrophe (here's) in it. So in the page source its showing like html entities of that character.
can we able to show as it is in the view page source like what we mentioned in the meta description.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Guess its best practice avoid of quote in meta. 
**The use of quotation marks actually results in truncation**, meaning that search engines will cut out this part of your meta description because it believes it to be a section of code, not text. If you would like to draw attention to something in your meta description, it is best to use apostrophes over quotation marks.

reference

https://www.fahrenheitmarketing.com/services/marketing/seo-tip-writing-a-compelling-meta-description/

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Abbas thanks for the explanation. But my current issue is iam using apostophe (here's) but in the source code its showing ascii value (here&#039) like this. I need to show as it is in the source code also